# Expected response 404 but received 500 in jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, http-status-code-404, response, http-status-code-500

I've written testcase for the below code where we try to delete the genre document if present in the DB, otherwise throw error with status code 404.

Code:

```
router.delete('/:id',[endpoint_middleware,admin_middleware], async (req, res) => {
    const doc_to_delete = await CollectionClass.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
    if (!doc_to_delete) return res.status(404).send('The genre with the given ID was not found.');
    res.send(doc_to_delete);
  });
```

Testcase:

```
describe('Delete genre', () => {
            let token;
            let curr_genre;
            let id;
            beforeEach(async () => {
                curr_genre = new CollectionClass({name: 'genre1'});
                await curr_genre.save(); 
                id = curr_genre._id;
                token = new UserCollectionClass({isAdmin : true}).generateToken();
            });
            const delete_genre = async () => {
                return await supertest(server)
                                    .delete('/api/genres/'+id)
                                    .set('x-jwtInHeader',token) 
                                    .send();
            };
            it('return error for deleting invalid id', async () => {
                id = 1;
                const response = await delete_genre();
                expect(response.status).toBe(404);
            });
});
```

The expected response status is 404 since the id is invalid. But the received response status is 500. Other test scenarios work as expected. Kindly help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue can be related to tests being not strictly isolated. Lets just try to debug a bit and improve the current code.

you have your delete handler, but I see it is error-prone as await operation is not handled well.

can you please try to replace it with this code and run tests again, you should see the exact error

```
router.delete("/:id", [endpoint_middleware, admin_middleware], async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doc_to_delete = await CollectionClass.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
    if (!doc_to_delete) return res.status(404).send("The genre with the given ID was not found.");
    res.send(doc_to_delete);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error(error)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @pauleg. This helped me to find the actual error!

Comment: @nandhini , happy to hear! can you please mention here what the error was, so it can also be useful for other people? thanks!

Comment: The have a middleware to validate the objectid. In this case, that middleware is responsible for throwing error for invalid id. I missed to attach that middleware in the code, and hence the testcase failed.